# Should StrToDate() with not parametrized TFormatSettings throw an AV?

Tags: delphi

Just for curiosity: why this code gives an AV instead of throwing an exception?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var fs: TFormatSettings;
begin
  strtodate('2011-01-01', fs);
end;
```

Comment: An access violation *is* an exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code raises an exception because `fs` is not initialized.

```
  uses SysUtis, Windows;

  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var fs: TFormatSettings;
  begin
    GetLocaleFormatSettings(GetSystemDefaultLCID, fs); // what is your short-date format?
    strtodate('2011-01-01', fs);
  end;
```

Comment: feel quite dumb now, just didn't expect that record type can lead to Access Violation

Comment: Local variables are not initialized at all. They contains random data and using that invalid data will cause AV.

Comment: Local `string` variables are initialized, Digi, and `TFormatSettings` includes fields of that type. They will be initialized. In Delphi 2005, and probably other versions, `StrToDate` calls `TryStrToDate`, which calls `ScanDate`, and `ScanDate` reads `FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat[1]` without checking whether `1` a valid index for that string. The error would have looked different if the RTL were compiled with range checking enabled.

Comment: In the general, **managed types** are initialized to whatever applicable null values.